# Email Auto-Replies not going to Reply-To Address

Tags: c#, email, smtp, office365, mailkit

I have a web app that sends emails via smtp on behalf of the user to their customers. I am able to put the user's email in the reply-to of the email and this works for normal email use for the users. In the case the recipient has an auto-responder or the email entered was incorrect email, the auto replies go to the sender not the reply-to. The sender inbox is unmonitored.

The sender email service is using and Office365 account.

What are my options to get the auto replies and returned emails to the reply-to email?

Comment: Why do you need to care about auto-responders? Do you need to know what an email was sent to invalid email address? If so, than you receive the email correctly - on the sender's side. Because the email has never been replied. Am I right?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev The auto-responders often contain important information like "the billing department contact email changed to ..." and the user will never see that.

Answer (score 2):

This may be because the autoresponders don't regard their messages as replies, but rather as messages from the email system itself.

Your mail has three or four addresses related to the sender, which generally show up at the recipient as Return-Path, Sender, From and Reply-To. Return-Path is who should get error messages and other messages from the email system itself, Sender and From are the address that should be displayed as having sent the mail and Reply-To is the address to which the addressee's replies should be directed. (Sender and From are only very rarely different these days, but historically Sender might be e.g. a particular member of a team while From is the team's shared address.)

Many autoresponders respond to the address that shows up as Return-Path in the final message (it's also called the envelope from address), so your options are:

- use the user's address as envelope from
- set up a forwarding scheme so that autoresponses are suitably forwarded

The first is very tricky wrt. DKIM, DMARC etc, so you'll probably find the second one simpler, even though it requires you to filter spam and perhaps more.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer! I've set sender, from, reply-to, and return-path, but none seem to work. What I was thinking is "injecting" some guid(linked to sender) into the email body and then I would need to poll the inbox for unread emails, scan the email for the guid, and forward that email to the corresponding sender. Not sure how well this would work or if it's a sound idea. Is there a better/robust place I can place/hide the guid?

Comment: What you suggest is quite common except that most people put the GUID in the SMTP sender address (the one called return-path in the finally delivered message). Its often called VERP, and you see it in a lot of mail, `Return-Path: foo-45782347urfhsdjf4we89rwefu@example.org`.

Comment: Also, separately: You shouldn't need to poll. Sensible mail servers can execute code when a message arrives. Your code looks up the GUID, finds the proper recipient, *filters away spam* and forwards the message *unless it's spam.* Simple, except for the italicised bit.

Comment: This is office356 Email.. so I don't have control of the server.. that I'm aware of.

Comment: Ah, Well, as they say, you can always make a simple problem unmanageably complicated by adding a few restrictions.

Comment: I ended up just adding a guid  to the References in the email headers when sending and logging that in the database. Then, a background service, checks the inbox every 5 minutes for unread emails, searches for references in the headers, if it finds one, looks up in database to match with the sender, and then forward the email to the sender.